# Can't install firebase with npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am working with `React`(if that matters). What I found about this around the google is to clear the npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Which didn't help. Also deleted `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file. Still the error bellow occur:

```
> grpc@1.24.2 install /var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.2 and node@10.19.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/src/node' 
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("toma") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/10.19.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-42-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-42-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/var/www/html/react/todoist/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.24.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.24.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-26T20_03_31_940Z-debug.log
```

This error seems to occur very often. Isn't there some straight forward solution? Or is it possible my `npm cache` to not get cleared after the `npm cache clean --force`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue, seems like firebase version in your package.json is older then it should be manually update it. I changed mine to the latest version on [Nmpjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) and that fixed it.